# How to utilize google map MarkerCluster to catch Polygon rather than marker ?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

everyone!

How to utilize google map MarkerCluster to catch Polygon rather than Marker ?

My program has about 20,000 markers on Google Map, and it becomes very slow when the data is loading into the map. Then I use JS code to draw one polygon as the replacement of marker. It would run faster. Maybe the PNG image loading for markers exercises negative influence on speed.

Finally, I read this article

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html

The function 'MarkerCluster' is great. However, it can be only used on the aspect of Google Marker.

```
var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, **markerArray**)
```

So is there some solution for putting polygon into this cluster mechanism ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tentatively made an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, #map_canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var mapCanvas;

      function initalize() {

        // Creating a map
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        mapCanvas = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Generate bunch of path data
        var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.448292, -152.012329);
        var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(76.150236, 58.925171);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
        mapCanvas.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        mapCanvas.setZoom(3);

        var baseLat, baseLng, category, json = [], path;
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          baseLat = Math.random() * (ne.lat() - sw.lat()) + sw.lat();
          baseLng = Math.random() * (ne.lng() - sw.lng()) + sw.lng();

          path = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(baseLat, baseLng),
            new google.maps.LatLng(baseLat + 1, baseLng + 1),
            new google.maps.LatLng(baseLat, baseLng + 2)
          ];
          json.push(path);
        }

        var bounds, polyList = [];
        for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
          var polyline = createPolygon(json[i]);
          polyList.push(polyline);
        }
        var clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(mapCanvas, polyList);
      }

      function createPolygon(path) {
        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          path : path,
          strokeOpacity : 1,
          strokeColor : "red"
        });

        var lastPath = null,
            lastCenter = null;
        polygon.getPosition = function() {
          var path = this.getPath();
          if (lastPath == path) {
            return lastCenter;
          }
          lastPath = path;
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          path.forEach(function(latlng, i) {
            bounds.extend(latlng);
          });

          lastCenter = bounds.getCenter()
          return lastCenter;
        };
        return polygon;
      }


      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initalize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I have read the source 'JS code' of class 'markerclusterer' and found that the important relationship between marker and cluster is 'POSITION', the object of 'google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)'. Yes, the sentence 'marker.getPosition' in these codes is KEY. So your code has gave polygon object the function 'getPosition' and it would return LatLng. As a result, it creates one replacement of marker by providing this function, which is great smart! :) Thank you !

Comment: much appreciated, useful solution.